# LINQ: Multiple Join With Max Revision Filter

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this line:

```
var transrevmax = db.TRANSACTs
    .Where(x => x.SITE == "1" && 
                x.DATE_IN >= dateinchoice && 
                x.DATE_OUT <= dateoutchoice)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TICKET_NO)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.REV_NO).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

and it returns the exact list of transactions I want the join below to go through to obtain values from...

```
var exportrecovery = (from trans in transrevmax
                      join detail in db.DETAILs on new { TICKET_NO = trans.TICKET_NO, REV_NO = trans.REV_NO } equals new { TICKET_NO = detail.TICKET_NO, REV_NO = detail.REV_NO }
                      join job in db.JOBs on new { JOB_CODE = trans.JOB_CODE, CUST_CODE = trans.CUST_CODE } equals new { JOB_CODE = job.CODE, CUST_CODE = job.CUST_CODE }
                      join customer in db.CUSTOMERs on trans.CUST_CODE equals customer.CODE
                      join invoiced in db.INVOICEDs on trans.TICKET_NO equals invoiced.TICKET_NO
                      where trans.DATE_IN >= dateinchoice && trans.DATE_OUT <= dateoutchoice && trans.STATUS.ToString().Trim() != "V" && trans.STATUS.ToString().Trim() != "E"
                      select new { ADDRESS = customer.ADDRESS, CITY = customer.CITY, STATE = customer.STATE, ZIP = customer.ZIP, FREIGHT = detail.HAUL_CHGE + detail.FUEL_CHGE, JOB_NAME = job.NAME, HAUL_TAX = detail.HAUL_TAX, INVOICE_NO = invoiced.INVOICE_NO, CUST_NAME = customer.NAME, TAX_CODE = customer.TAX_CODE, MAT_CHGE = detail.MAT_CHGE, MAT_TAX = detail.MAT_TAX, MAT_CODE = detail.MAT_CODE, QTY = detail.QTY, PRICE = detail.PRICE, DATE_MOD = trans.DATE_OUT, REV_NO = trans.REV_NO, SITE = trans.SITE, TICKET_NO = trans.TICKET_NO, CUST_CODE = trans.CUST_CODE, JOB_CODE = trans.JOB_CODE }
                      ).ToList();
```

... if I run the first line I get the transactions limited to only those with the max revision (what I want), and if I run the join (replacing the "transrevmax" with the table "db.TRANSACTs") I get the right range of ticket numbers, but it includes all revisions. I am stumped as to how I can use the joined tables and get only unique rows according to their (maximum) revision number. When these two are used in conjunction I receive zero rows. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ToList` on the `transrevmax` creation.

Comment: Worked like a charm! In the meantime I discovered that if i dropped the where portion in the first line (transrevmax) and used it as a subsequent filter for my unwieldy join that it would yield the desired results (I added the "where site=" section to the query itself) as well. Thank you for your solution and your help.